# socket 404 error in nestjs/react environment that I don't know why

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

i don't know why it returns a 404 error even though it seems to have worked in a standard way
i've been trying to find the cause all day, but I can't find it.
if anyone knows about this issue, I would be very grateful if you could let me know

[errorMessage] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
[errorMessage] GET http://localhost:3001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Oaywi1f 404 (Not Found)

-- this is my source --
**nestjs / chat.gateway.ts**

```
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  ConnectedSocket,
  MessageBody,
  OnGatewayConnection,
  OnGatewayDisconnect,
  OnGatewayInit,
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
  WebSocketServer,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Namespace, Socket } from 'socket.io';


@WebSocketGateway({
  path: '/api/chat',
  namespace: 'chat',
  cors: {
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
  },
})

@WebSocketGateway(3000, { transports: ['websocket'] })
export class ChatGateway implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect
{
  private logger = new Logger('Gateway');

  @WebSocketServer() nsp: Namespace;


  @SubscribeMessage('message')
  handleMessage(
    @ConnectedSocket() socket: Socket,
    @MessageBody() message: string,
  ) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', { username: socket.id, message });
    return { username: socket.id, message };
  }
}
```

**nestjs/chat.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ChatGateway } from './chat.gateway';

@Module({
    providers: [ChatGateway],
})
export class ChatModule {}
```

**reactjs/chat.tsx**

```
import Footer from 'components/common/footer';
import Header from 'components/common/header';
import { ChangeEvent, FormEvent, useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

const path = "http://localhost:3001/chat"
const socket = io(path);
```

**nestjs/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/axios": "^0.0.7",
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^1.2.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "^1.0.1",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^9.0.3",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^8.2.1",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-socket.io": "^10.0.5",
    "@nestjs/throttler": "^2.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.0.3",
    "@nestjs/websockets": "^10.0.5",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.6",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "axios-observable": "^1.4.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cache-manager": "^3.6.0",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.2",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "joi": "^17.6.0",
    "mapped-types": "^0.0.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.7",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "passport": "^0.5.2",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-kakao": "^1.0.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.5",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.43"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/cache-manager": "^3.4.3",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.17.4",
    "@types/jest": "27.4.0",
    "@types/joi": "^17.2.3",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/passport-kakao": "^0.2.1",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.34",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.2.5",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.10.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

**reactjs/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^38.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^6.0.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/next": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.25",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.39",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.25",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/react-select": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/universal-cookie": "^3.0.0",
    "batch": "^0.6.1",
    "browser-image-compression": "^2.0.2",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.0",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.63.6",
    "styled-component": "^2.8.0",
    "swiper": "^9.3.2",
    "typesafe-actions": "^5.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm start\" \"npm run start --prefix frontend\""
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

i want socket to communicate